# Click button id with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have the following HTML code from an "accept-cookie" window:

```
<div id="_name-buttons"> 
    <button id="_name-preferences">[...]</button> 
    <button id="_name-accept">[...]</button>
```

I am trying to use Selenium to click on the button `_name-accept`, namely accept the cookies.
My code does the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

...

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, '_name-accept'))).click()
```

however it doesn't work and I have this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16
```

How can I click that button id? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element instead of ***id*** you  can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#_name-buttons button#_name-accept"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='_name-buttons']//button[@id='_name-accept']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) When I am trying your strategy I have this error: 


```selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16```

Comment: Found the issue in my approach
The button was part of a iframe, so I had to select the iframe first and click the button afterwards

Comment: @Frank8992 Glad to be able to help you.